# numpy: FutureWarning: future versions will not create a writeable array from broadcast_array. Set the writable flag explicitly to avoid this warning

Tags: python, numpy

The following snippet raises a warning in numpy v1.24:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.array(0)
y = np.array([1, 2, 3])
x_, y_ = np.broadcast_arrays(x, y)


x_.flags.writeable
# FutureWarning: future versions will not create a writeable array from broadcast_array. Set the writable flag explicitly to avoid this warning.
```

How to mitigate?

Comment: Do you need to write to `x_`?

Comment: @hpaulj I didn't need to write to `x_`, but I wanted to get rid of the warning, and it took me a while to realize that simply accessing the flag caused it

Comment: The latest docs explains why writing can be a problem, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_arrays.html

Answer (score 1):

Given that the result of `numpy.broadcast_arrays` won't be writeable in a future version of numpy, it's best to anticipate the change and explicitly set the array to read-only:

```py
x_.flags.writeable = False
```

Once it's done, accessing `x_.flags.writeable` won't create a warning.

Also, setting the broadcasted array `x_` to read-only has no change on the base array `x`:

```py
x_.flags.writeable
# False

x.flags.writeable
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code (in numpy 1.24)

```
In [340]: x_
Out[340]: array([0, 0, 0])

In [341]: x_.strides
Out[341]: (0,)
```

The strides means that all elements of `x_` are the same, a `view` of the one element of `x`.

```
In [342]: x_[0]
Out[342]: 0
```

Setting an element, works, but also raises a warning:

```
In [343]: x_[0]=1
C:\Users\14256\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_12988\3649538002.py:1: DeprecationWarning: Numpy has detected that you (may be) writing to an array with
overlapping memory from np.broadcast_arrays. If this is intentional
set the WRITEABLE flag True or make a copy immediately before writing.
  x_[0]=1
```

As of this version, the writable flag is still True:

```
In [346]: x_.flags
Out[346]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False

In [347]: x_
Out[347]: array([1, 1, 1])
In [349]: x
Out[349]: array(1)
```

Trying to set 3 elements of `x_` results in only the last having effect:

```
In [350]: x_[:]=[1,2,3]

In [351]: x
Out[351]: array(3)

In [352]: x_
Out[352]: array([3, 3, 3])
```

Comment: Nice illustration of why it's a bad idea to have writeable broadcast arrays. It makes perfect sense that numpy emits a warning when writing such an array. The warning for merely accessing a flag threw me off though.